# Zero input_file_names in Grep

Tags: grep

From the manual for `grep`, the general form of grep usage is:

```
grep options pattern input_file_names
```

In particular, it is stated "There can be zero or more input file names."

What files are candidates for the search, if there are zero file names? Ex. `grep mystr`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`man grep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/grep.1posix.html):

```
   file   A pathname of a file to be searched for the patterns. If no file
          operands are specified, the standard input shall be used.
```

So it will wait for you type some text if there's no pipeline or redirection involved.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I was reading http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.pdf and it doesn't have the info you quoted. Are these manuals written by different people? I assume there is only one grep?

Comment: There many `grep`s. I linked to the POSIX manual, which most forms of `grep` will treat as a base, including the GNU grep. The manual you linked to does mention this, but in a more verbose way (see section 2.4).

Comment: @boxofchalk1 Actually, if you'd said you are using GNU grep, I would have linked to a manpage for the GNU grep: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/grep.1.html, which has this information in the first line.

Comment: Thanks muru. Actually, I did not know there were different `grep`s. But I just did `grep -V` and found I am indeed running GNU grep (which came with CentOS). This is off-topic, but are there Linux distributions that installs the POSIX version instead?

Comment: @boxofchalk1 there is no single POSIX version, since it is a standard that's implemented by others. On Linux, you are certain to be using GNU grep, since Linux and GNU go hand in hand (that's why it's sometimes called GNU/Linux). Debian has the Plan9 grep in its repositories, but i don't know if CentOS has that.

Answer (score 2):

It reads from its *standard input* (file descriptor 0) if not given any filename.

```
grep foo
```

is equivalent to:

```
grep foo -
```

That allows things like:

```
grep foo < file
```

Or:

```
cmd | grep foo
```

If `grep foo` is run at the prompt of an interactive shell in a terminal, then `grep` will read from the terminal device, so from what you enter via the keyboard.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! As muru's answer came first and resolved my question, I've accepted that answer. Thanks again.